# Ubuntu dual boot breaks after booting Windows

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, dual-boot

I've installed Windows and Ubuntu 22.04 on two separate drives.

Windows always boots fine. However, if I want to switch over to Ubuntu, after restarting the computer and selecting the Ubuntu boot option, it will load for a little longer than usual, show me the home screen, and then shutdown.

- I've tried using the `nomodeset` parameter when booting ubuntu, but that does not seem to work. Secure boot is off.
- I've reinstalled ubuntu multiple times, no dice.
- What's more, my bootable USB stick is failing in the same way.

Any ideas what Windows is doing that is causing Ubuntu to fail?

It's aGgigabyte motherboard and an nVidia graphics card. Unfortunately, I cannot install BootRepair. When I open the terminal in recovery mode and connect to the internet it shuts down.

Comment: What brand/model computer? What video card/chip? If you are getting to home screen, not really a boot issue, but perhaps report will show something in configuration. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair You should not need to run fix, just report.

Comment: It's a gigabyte motherboard and an nvidia graphics card. Unfortunately, I cannot install BootRepair. When I open the terminal in recovery mode and connect to the internet it shuts down:/

Comment: I disabled NetworkManager with `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service` from the recovery terminal and now it's not shutting down on me! Super stoked! I'll update this thread once I learn more.

Comment: If nVidia, did you boot live installer in Safe Mode? And then install optional extra/restricted drivers to get nVidia driver installed? If not from recovery mode you can install nVidia driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478024/how-do-i-install-an-arbitrary-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-driver-on-ubuntu-studio-22 `ubuntu-drivers list --gpgpu` Available see recommended driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the the default Windows driver for my `Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller`  was somehow being loaded by Ubuntu on startup, instead of the Ubuntu version.

I'm unsure why this was happening, but disabling NetworkManager with `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service` in the recovery terminal allowed me to successfully boot without crashing.